# Bright Yellow Spider with spots/lines

Tags: identification, insects

Trying to identify this little guy I found crawling around outside (Pittsburgh, PA area). It is a bright yellow spider with black spots and lines on it.

[image: bright yellow spider with black spots and lines]

The only thing I turned up in my searches was the Yellow Crab Spider, but I did not see any pictures of one with black marking in the pattern of my picture (if any they had red marking on the sides).

(Note: Used [insects](/questions/tagged/insects) as there was no [arachnids](/questions/tagged/arachnids) and wasn't sure if it is needed.)

Comment: Hi Skooba, this is not really a gardening question

Comment: @kevinskio Why not? Has meta policy changed here, there are tons of identification questions here for insects and the like.

Comment: From Help on what kind of questions can I ask here:  identification ... of animals that are affecting your garden or houseplants;   Hard to see how Spiders are affecting the garden in this context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a crab spider of some kind. There are lots of kinds.

Here are some links with pictures that look like yours:

- http://mobugs.blogspot.com/2009/11/crab-spiders.html
- https://naturegardensnhm.blogspot.com/2012/02/killer-legs-crab-spider-wins-prize-with.html (This one's a white-banded crab spider.)

Supposedly, crab spiders can change colors (so, yours may not always be yellow).